# Accessing class/subclass functions and properties from inside event handlers

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, events, extends

(This is something of a follow up from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55983396/can-a-child-class-respond-to-events-captured-by-its-super), but I've included all necessary context here.)

I am trying to create a system of HTML interface elements which will use a lot of shared code, and I'm having trouble dealing with event handlers and scope. This code is working:

```js
class Inator {
  constructor(whichCanvas, eventRegistry) {
    this.myCanvas = whichCanvas;
    this.foo = 10;
    for (var e in eventRegistry) {
      this.myCanvas.addEventListener(e,eventRegistry[e]);
    }
  }
  double(val) {
   return val*2;
  }
}

class Ballgowninator extends Inator {
  constructor(whichCanvas) {
    super(
     whichCanvas, {
        mousedown: (e) => {
          alert("mousedown");
        },
        mouseup: (e) => {
          alert("mouseup");
        }
      }
    );
    this.bar = 20;
  }
  triple(val) {
    return val*3;
  }
}

var c = new Ballgowninator(document.querySelector(".ballgown"));
```

```css
.inator {
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 1px black;
  width: 90vw;
}
```

```html
<canvas class="ballgown inator"></canvas>
```

([Same code](https://jsfiddle.net/TobyRush/1xjcmy4v/36/) as a JSFiddle, if you prefer)

However, I'd like to be able to access `double()`, `triple()`, `foo` and `bar` from inside the event handlers that I'm passing to `super()`. Is this even possible with the set up I have, or is there a better way to rework this entire approach?

Thank you!

Comment: `this.` will access your classes "properties"

Comment: Ugh, I swear I tried this, but you're right, it accesses everything from within the handlers. Now I feel dumb.

Comment: happens to the best :D

Comment: just a note, `this` bind to your instance instead of `HTMLElement` because you use arrow function. You may need to think about which you want.

Comment: I'm new to arrow functions so this info is very helpful. Thanks!